# Unable to start z/OS Apache web-server

Tags: apache, mainframe, zos

I've moved to a new job/site and I'm trying to configure the Apache web-server on a z/OS 2.2 test system. I'm using the instructions here : http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4987.pdf in section 3.5 Sample real-world setup process.

I did this at my last site with no issues, but here the server task starts and then stops.

In my `proc.errors`, I have:

```
grep: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/envvars 46: .: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl 53: FSUM7351 not found
[: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl 77: FSUM7351 not found                                                      
[: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl 90: FSUM7351 not found                                                      
[: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/chk_links 13: FSUM7351 not found                                                      
echo: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/chk_links 17: FSUM7351 not found                                                   
[: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl 96: FSUM7351 not found                                                      
[Thu May 10 15:51:51.594700 2018] [core:crit] [pid 50332667:tid 2020277849247711232] (139)EDC5139I Operation not permitted. (errno2=0x05DA05FD): AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
```

in `proc.output`, I have:

```
Running -sh            <= I added an 'echo Running $0' to /etc/profile'                                                                                     
 values of $CAIGLBL0000 and $PATH                                                                           
/cai/tngfw                                                                                                  
/cai/tngfw/bin:/bin:.:/usr/lpp/Printsrv/bin:.                                                               
                **************************************************************                              
                *                    UNIX System Services                    *                              
                **************************************************************                              
Thu May 10 15:51:51 BST 2018                                                                                
apachectl.sh starting       <= added 'echo apachectl.sh starting' to apachectl.sh                                                                                
IHSAE001                    <= added 'whoami' to apachectl.sh                                                                                         
path=/cai/tngfw/bin:/bin:.:/usr/lpp/Printsrv/bin:.:/cai/tngfw/gui/bin:/cai/tngfw/scripts:/cai/tngfw/snmp/bin    <= added 'echo path=$PATH' to apachectl.sh
```

The messages in proc.errors seems to be saying that basic shell commands aren;t working; researching the message `AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator` implies that this error is a symptom of a bad path and not the real error.

If I try the command to start the server (the one int he IHSAE001 STC JCL) myself from a PUTTY session, I get something very similar:

```
# /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl -k start -f conf/httpd.conf -DNO_DETACH
apachectl.sh starting
JOCS065
path=/cai/tngfw/bin:/bin:.:/usr/lpp/Printsrv/bin:.:/cai/tngfw/gui/bin:/cai/tngfw/scripts:/cai/tngfw/snmp/bin
grep: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/envvars 46: .: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl 53: FSUM7351 not found
[: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl 77: FSUM7351 not found
[: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl 90: FSUM7351 not found
[: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/chk_links 13: FSUM7351 not found
echo: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/chk_links 17: FSUM7351 not found
[: /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin/apachectl 96: FSUM7351 not found
```

As far as I'm aware, I've followed the setup as it is in the Red Book, except for where I've changed security defintions for RACF to ACF2.

The webserver is running under the ACF2 user IHSAE001, who's homedir is `/usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001`

Comment: What's your permissions for /usr/lpp/ihsconfig/ihs/ihsae001/bin ?

Comment: @steveives is this still an issue for you or what was the resolution?

Comment: Sorry guys - forgot I’d asked this. Ran the setup again but installed the files to my own homedir. Then gave myself UID(0) (bad, I know) to eliminate permission errors. Also made sure my PATH had IBM standard/required directories in it. Eventually worked after application of a necessary ACF2 PTF. Not yet had time to run *without* UID(0) as it should be 8n production.